# i make the enter key work like tab using FocusTraversalKeys() but if i want to perform any action on any component on enter key then how to do that?

Tags: java, swing

i make the enter key work like a tab in a Jframe using setFocusTraversalKeys() but at a textField by presssing a enter i want to open a new frame how to do that becasue of this method by pressing enter the focus go to the another component but the action can not be performed .

```
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(140, 40, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(140, 89, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(First.this,
                           "either Date is not within financial year or not a valide date",
                                "Inane warning",
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        textField_2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(First.this,
                               "either Date is not within financial year or not a valide date",
                                    "Inane warning",
                                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        });
        textField_2.setBounds(140, 148, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        Set forwardKeys = getFocusTraversalKeys(
                KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
        Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys);
        newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
        setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
                newForwardKeys);
    }
}
```

Comment: intercept the event, and check what key was pressed. if enter -> perform this, else, perform something else

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. We don't need your whole application. Just minimal code to demonstrate the problem. So you need a JFrame with a text field and another component. You add the ActionListener to the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the problem by setting `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)` on that particular component, after that the `ActionListener` starts working.